# Sticky position not working with safari mobile

Tags: css, angular, navbar

I want my navbar to be sticky. The css works fine with Chrome on my desktop but when I try to view it on my iPhone the navbar no longer sticks. I've tried to mess with the body overflow and applying the sticky position on other elements but can't get it to work. Not sure what is wrong or what to do to fix this. I am using Angular 6 for my app and would like to avoid using JS or Jquery to solve this issue.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="contact-info"></div>

<app-navbar>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <nav class="navbar">
        my navbar links......
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer-bar></app-footer-bar>
```

**navbar.component.css**

```
.outer {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Safari version ?

Comment: What version of Safari do you use?

Comment: is there a table in your header? it could be a table issue [there's a lot of issues with sticky and tables according to caniuse.com] or the fact that you have 2 rules for position in your css. I would recommend removing the second rule and retesting it to see if the error still occurs

Comment: @RachelGallen No table. I figured out what my issue is if you see my comment below but I do not know how to solve the problem. My sticky is only being restricted to the navbar component but I would like it to be sticky for my entire app no matter what component I am viewing.

Comment: @CuongVo are you using React or something? (That's a different ball of wax!) If so, you'd have to make the component have a fixed position, I made a bottom tab bar for the first app I developed, but I studied someone else's code first cos I was only learning . You could probably do the same. Sorry I couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 3):

Sticky is not supported in IE/Edge 15 or earlier. Supported in Safari from version 6.1 with a -webkit- prefix.

To test it I created below snippet which is working fine on Safari, Chrome, Firefox on MacOS.

```css
.outer {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

body {
height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <nav class="navbar">
        my navbar links......
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont think this is my issue because I have my sticky position working on some navigation pills inside of another component. But to answer the question I was able to pull this up on my phone i was able to pull this up for my version: Mozilla/5.0(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS11_4_1 like MacOS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

Comment: Ok. Your code revealed to me what is going on. The navbar is sticky but only to the body of my navbar component. How would I make my navbar component sticky for all of my components?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a work around for my problem using angular coding and a fixed position. If someone knows how to do this with the css sticky position then that would be appreciated.

**navbar.component.html**

```
<div class="outer" [class.sticky]="sticky" #stickyNavbar>
```

**navbar.component.css**

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;  
}
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('stickyNavbar') navbarElement: ElementRef;

sticky: boolean = false;
navbarPosition: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.navbarPosition = this.navbarElement.nativeElement.offsetTop;
  }

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  handleScroll() {
    const windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if(windowScroll > this.navbarPosition) {
      this.sticky = true;
    } else {
      this.sticky = false;
    }
  }
}
```